# Helpr running this program

Tags: python

My code currently looks like this

```
def Process (Name, Score):

S = ""

Count = 0

    while (Count < Score):
        Count = Count + 1
        S = S + "|"
    #S = S + Name, Score 
    S = S + Name
    S = S + str(Score)

    return S

def Main():

    Names = ["Fred","Sam","Mary","Carol","Joe","Bob","Sue"]
    Scores = [78,34,97,69,82,46,89]
    L = 7 #list length
    Count2 = 0  
    while (Count2 < L):
        Process (Names[0 + Count2], Scores[0 + Count2])
        Count2 = Count2 + 1


    return
```

I want to be able to run Process (Name, Score) with the 2 corresponding lists in the Main() program. The Process program returns a text bar graph with the name and score, and I want to show all 7 at once, while being able to change lists at a future date. So far hat I have in Main() is not working, but Process does. 
Thanks in advance if you can help!

Comment: What is wrong with Main(). Is it being called from anywhere?

Comment: Also, `Process()` returns a value, but when you call it from `Main()`, you aren't assigning the returned value anywhere, so it is lost.

Comment: simplest fix, maybe need to add a last line to call `Main()` as:
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()` . Then in `Main()` add a `print` statement before call to `Process()` using `print Process (Names[0 + Count2], Scores[0 + Count2])`, this will display the return value from `Process()`. But, you'll still need to handle changing the list contents in `Main()`, `Names = [...]` to the new list items

Comment: I am very new, so I am a little confused on how to successfully call back the process function to get this to work! what would you add and where would be extremely helpful if possible. thank you guys

Comment: I found my solution, thank you guys for the help!